# Unexpected behavior of BSplineFunction and BezierFunction

Tags: splines

```
$Version
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[RandomInteger[100,{3,2}]][t],{t,0,1}]
```

> 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 17, 2016)
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Crazy result.But the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierFunction.html) have not any specification for this.And the `BezierFunction` and `BSplineFunction` have a same behavior in my PC.

---

And when I input like this

```
temp = RandomInteger[100, {3, 2}];
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[temp][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

We'll get the right answer.If anybody can confirm this.I'll add a bug for this post and give a support to wolfram.

Comment: happens also in V9.

Comment: You say `BSplineFunction[]` in the title, but `BezierFunction[]` in the body. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: try `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@BezierFunction[RandomInteger[100, {3, 2}]][t], {t, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: ... or `ParametricPlot[
 BezierFunction[RandomInteger[100, {3, 2}]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: @J.M. It's a typo.And thanks for your point out that.

Comment: @kglr Thanks your solution.Maybe the culprit is the attribution names `HoldAll` of `ParametricPlot`.Can you make that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What is happening:** For every value of `t` that is sampled a new triple of `Randominteger` pairs is generated and a new `BezierFunction` is constructed. So every `t` that is sampled is processed with a different function. This can be seen using `Trace` on a simpler version of the problem.

```
Trace[ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[RandomInteger[100, {3, 2}]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints ->3, MaxRecursion -> 0,  AspectRatio -> 1], BezierFunction| RandomInteger]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Solution:** `Evaluate`ing the first argument of `ParametricPlot` or using the option `Evaluated->True` gives the expected output.

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@BezierFunction[RandomInteger[100, {3, 2}]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[RandomInteger[100, {3, 2}]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Evaluated -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]